# Spring Integration: Why is client socket waiting for response from server?

Tags: java, spring, sockets, spring-integration

I am using spring integration to make a client socket (java code), which must send messages to server socket (flash client). Basically, i want to push messages to flash through socket communication without caring for any response from it. The message which should be sent is coming from GW upon send method is called.

I am able to push a message, but the problem is that my client socket is waiting for a response and if it doesn't get one it times out at some point. Here is my configuration:

```
<int:gateway id="gw"
    service-interface="integration.MessageGateway"
    default-request-channel="input"/>

<int-ip:tcp-connection-factory id="client"
    type="client"
    host="localhost"
    port="6767"
    serializer="clientSerializer"
    single-use="true" so-keep-alive="true"
    so-timeout="10000"/>

<bean id="clientSerializer" class="org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.serializer.ByteArrayCrLfSerializer" />

<int:channel id="input" />

<int-ip:tcp-outbound-gateway id="outGateway"
    request-channel="input"
    connection-factory="client"
    request-timeout="10000"
    reply-timeout="10000"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider to use `one-way` `<int-ip:tcp-outbound-channel-adapter>`: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/ip.html#tcp-adapters